# Which Java APIs create Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Without having the source code for a Java API, is there anyway to know if the API methods create multiple threads ? Are there any conventions to follow if you are writing Java APIs and they create multiple threads. This may be very fundamental question but it happened to spawn out of a discussion in which the crux question was - " How do you know which Java APIs create threads and which don't " ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way of determining which libraries create new threads is by disallowing `Thread` creation and `ThreadGroup` modification in the `SecurityManager`. See the `java.lang.SecurityManager.checkAccess(Thread)` method. By implementing your own `SecurityManager`, you are able to react on the creation of Threads.

To answer the other question: many libraries create new threads, even if you don't expect it. For example APIs for HTTP communication create Timers for Keep-Alives or session timeouts. Java 2D is creating a signalling thread. Java itself has multiple threads, e.g. the Finalizer thread; the AWT/Swing event dispatcher thread etc.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if you are looking at core java, not J2EE, the only time I can think that threads are created in core Java is with Swing.

I haven't seen any example of other threads being created by the core Java APIs, except for the Thread class, of course. :)

But, if you are using other libraries then it may be that they are creating threads, but, if you don't want to profile, you may want to use AspectJ to log whenever a new thread is created, and the stack track of what called it, so you can see what is creating the threads.

**UPDATE:**

Swing uses 4 threads, according to this post, but he also explains how you can go about killing off the threads, if needed.

http://www.herongyang.com/Swing/jframe_2.html

Comment: As far as I know, Swing (actually, AWT) only creates a single event dispatch thread, which you access through `SwingUtilities`'s `invokeLater` and `invokeAndWait` methods.

Comment: @R. Bemrose - I am not certain if Swing creates more than one, it seemed that it doesn't but that is why I put "may", as I am not 100% certain.

Comment: in the debugger of eclipse I can see at least 3 Threads ("AWT-EventQueue", "AWT-Windows", "AWT-Shutdown") when opening a single JFrame. Somtimes I also see a "DestroyJavaVM" thread, only if using AWT/Swing.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to tell. Actually, I don't think you normally would care that much unless you're in some kind of constrained environment. What's I've found is more relevant is to determine if a method is written with an expectation of being run on a particular thread (the AWT Event dispatch thread, in the case I've seen). There's not a way to do that either, unless the code is using some kind of naming convention, or it's documented.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see active threads, just fire up the jvisualvm application (located in your $JDK/bin directory) to connect to any local java process.  You'll be able to see a multitude of information about the process, including thread names, status, and history.  Get more information [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html).